# Getting Response is not defined error even after correct import statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to determine instanceof Response in the following code:

`if (!(res instanceof Response)) res = null`

I have used the following import statement to import Response from express

`import { Response } from 'express';`

Still, I am getting this error:
`{"date":"Tue Jul 26 2022 13:21:42 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)","error":{},"exception":true,"level":"error","message":"uncaughtException: Response is not defined\nReferenceError: Response is not defined`

What precisely am I doing wrong in this scenario?